# Sequelize And / Or Operators

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to reproduce this query in Sequelize:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 5 AND (login = 1 OR register = 1)
```

I was looking on docs and here's my currently code:

```
Model.findOne({
        where: Sequelize.and({
            id: 5
            }, Sequelize.or({
                login: 1,
                register: 1
            })
        )
    })
```

But it's not working. I'm pretty new in Sequelize, hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "not working?" do you get an error? does it return something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
Model.findOne({
    where: Sequelize.and({
        id: 5
        }, Sequelize.or(
               {login: 1},
               {register: 1}
           )
    )
})
```